# Build KeePass 2.0 Alpha 6 in Fedora

Tags: linux, build, fedora, qmake, keepass

I want to build KeePass 2.0 Alpha 6 in Fedora but it doesn't work the 'normal' way. I could build older KeePass versions (non-alpha) with [this tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/installation-of-keepassx-password-manager-on-fedora-linux).

I'm starting with downloading the tarball

```
wget https://www.keepassx.org/dev/attachments/download/69/keepassx-2.0-alpha6.tar.gz
```

then I'm unpacking it and changing to its directory with

```
tar xzf keepassx-2.0-alpha6.tar.gz
cd keepassx-2.0-alpha6/
```

but when I try to compile it with

```
qmake-qt4
```

I get the following

```
QMake has two modes, one mode for generating project files based on
some heuristics, and the other for generating makefiles. Normally you
shouldn't need to specify a mode, as makefile generation is the default
mode for qmake, but you may use this to test qmake on an existing project

Mode:
  -project       Put qmake into project file generation mode
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as files to
                 be built,
                 defaults to *.c; *.ui; *.y; *.l; *.ts; *.xlf; *.qrc; *.h; *.hpp; *.hh; *.hxx; *.H; *.cpp; *.cc; *.cxx; *.C
                 Note: The created .pro file probably will 
                 need to be edited. For example add the QT variable to 
                 specify what modules are required.
  -makefile      Put qmake into makefile generation mode (default)
                 In this mode qmake interprets files as project files to
                 be processed, if skipped qmake will try to find a project
                 file in your current working directory

Warnings Options:
  -Wnone         Turn off all warnings; specific ones may be re-enabled by
                 later -W options
  -Wall          Turn on all warnings
  -Wparser       Turn on parser warnings
  -Wlogic        Turn on logic warnings (on by default)
  -Wdeprecated   Turn on deprecation warnings (on by default)

Options:
   * You can place any variable assignment in options and it will be     *
   * processed as if it was in [files]. These assignments will be parsed *
   * before [files].                                                     *
  -o file        Write output to file
  -d             Increase debug level
  -t templ       Overrides TEMPLATE as templ
  -tp prefix     Overrides TEMPLATE so that prefix is prefixed into the value
  -help          This help
  -v             Version information
  -after         All variable assignments after this will be
                 parsed after [files]
  -norecursive   Don't do a recursive search
  -recursive     Do a recursive search
  -set <prop> <value> Set persistent property
  -unset <prop>  Unset persistent property
  -query <prop>  Query persistent property. Show all if <prop> is empty.
  -cache file    Use file as cache           [makefile mode only]
  -spec spec     Use spec as QMAKESPEC       [makefile mode only]
  -nocache       Don't use a cache file      [makefile mode only]
  -nodepend      Don't generate dependencies [makefile mode only]
  -nomoc         Don't generate moc targets  [makefile mode only]
  -nopwd         Don't look for files in pwd [project mode only]
```

Could the command be incomplete? I hope that anybody can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This version uses CMake.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Read `INSTALL` file for details.